# Combining Ghostery and HTTPS-Everywhere on Android?

Tags: security, browser, chrome-for-android, encryption, firefox-for-android

On my PC (Windows 8.1) I am happily using Firefox with the Addons *Ghostery* and *HTTPS-Everywhere*. I really like this combination so I winder how I can achieve the same things on my Android phone.

- I tried the **Ghostery Browser for Android** which however does not bring HTTPS-Everywhere-like functionality and offers no way to install such a plugin either.
- I tried installig **Firefox for Android** and installing the Ghostify and HTTPS-Everywhere addons. This works *quite* well but is not very comfortable to use and quite slow. Also, Firefox crashes from time to time and does not cache loaded tabs in a way that they can still be viewed when offline without reloading. This is my favourite feature of Google Chrome and it would be a pity to do without.

So is there any way to combine the functionality of Ghostery, HTTPS-Everywhere and the nice Google Chrome functionality and its lightweightness?

... on Android?